# ASP.Net MVC Go To Declaration On view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there anyway when in an MVC view to right click a function call and get to the declaration? Like you can do in the code behind/controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with resharper: control click on it.

Comment: I don't think vs 2008 have that built-in for aspx/ascx.

Answer (score 0):

Double-click to select, global find (button near the search box at the top), and then you usually have only couple of search results so you can easily see the function. If it's not in your code but in some lib, then I think you'll have to copy it, open Object Explorer, and search for it. With keyboard shortcuts not so bad; or you can write a VS macro to do it ;-)

But there's even easier way - copy, Alt-Tab to FireFox, and google for it ;-)